# How to set DrawerItem on top of Drawer Screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer

I created a drawer with screens but wanted to add also an image of the user at the top of the drawer. I used in the Drawer.Navigator the drawerContent option and used a custom function and called it. The problem is that the image is set on the bottom and not in the top. I've tried searching in the web but I didn't find a way to set it on top. Here is the code:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

const CustomDrawerContent=(props) =>{
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
        icon={({color})=> <Image style={{ width: 90, height: 90, borderRadius: 400 / 2 }} source={{ uri: auth.currentUser.photoURL }}></Image>}
        label=""
      />
      
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
   return (
    
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='TabNavigator' drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent}> 
        <Drawer.Screen name='Início' component={TabNavigator}/>[enter image description here][1]
        <Drawer.Screen name="Lista de Espera" component={PermissionsStackScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Comunidade" component={CommunityStackScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='Análises em Espera' component={AwaitingStackScreen}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Confirmar Análises' component={VerifyStackScreen}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Análises Rejeitadas' component={RejectedStackScreen}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Gerir Reagentes' component={ReagentStackScreen}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Gerir Equipamentos' component={EquipmentStackScreen}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
  
}

export default DrawerNavigator
```

I have also added the link of the how the code looks like.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b9f5.jpg

Any help would be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply change the order of the component here :

```js
const CustomDrawerContent=(props) =>{
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      {/* Render image item first */}
      <DrawerItem
        icon={({color})=> <Image style={{ width: 90, height: 90, borderRadius: 400 / 2 }} source={{ uri: auth.currentUser.photoURL }}></Image>}
        label=""
      />
      {/* then render others menu item */}
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```